# $\operatorname{Jac}(R,a)=\lambda R^m b$ implies that $b \in k$? $a,b,R \in k[x,y]$

Tags: polynomials, commutative-algebra, jacobian

Let $k$ be a field of characteristic zero, and let $k[x,y]$ be the polynomial ring in two variables $x$ and $y$.
Let $a,b,R \in k[x,y]$. By definition, $\operatorname{Jac}(R,a):=R_xa_y-R_ya_x$.

Assume that $\operatorname{Jac}(R,a)=\lambda R^mb$, for some $\lambda \in k-\{0\}$ and $m \in \mathbb{N}$.

> Is it true that $b \in k-\{0\}$? Or can one find an easy counterexample?

**Example for $\lambda=b=1$ and $m=2$:** Take $R=x^2y^3$ and $a=-x^3y^4$. Then,  $R_x=2xy^3$, $R_y=3x^2y^2$, $a_x=-3x^2y^4$, $a_y=-4x^3y^3$.

Therefore, $\operatorname{Jac}(R,a)=(2xy^3)(-4x^3y^3)-(3x^2y^2)(-3x^2y^4)=
-8x^4y^6+9x^4y^6=x^4y^6=R^2$.

Any hints and comments are welcome!

Comment: Try $a=RS$ for a polynomial $S$.

Comment: @Mohan, very nice counterexample!

Comment: @Mohan, please, must $a$ be a multiple of $R$ in order to obtain that $b$ is not necessarily a scalar? (Example 1: $\operatorname{Jac}(R,-R^mS)=\operatorname{Jac}(R^mS,R)=R^m\operatorname{Jac}(S,R)$.  Example 2: $a=\sum -R_i^{m_i}S_i$, with $m_i \geq 1$, then $\operatorname{Jac}(R,a)=\sum R^{m_i}\operatorname{Jac}(S_i,R)=R\tilde{S}$. In these two examples, $a$ is a multiple of $R$).

Comment: No, you can for example take $a=RS+1$.

Comment: @Mohan, thank you very much.

Comment: What if we require that each of $\{a,b,R\}$ is homogeneous? In this case $S$ should be homogeneous. Now $RS+1$ will be homogeneous only when both $R$ and $S$ are homogeneous of degree zero.

Comment: @user237522 I think it gets more involved there because in characteristic $0$, $Jac(R,T) = 0$ for homogeneous polynomials $R,T$ will imply that either $R$ divides $T$ or $T$ divides $R$.  Mohan's example is based on the identity $Jac(R, RS + T) = R Jac(R,S) + Jac(R, T)$ and choosing $S, T$ so that $Jac(R,S)$ is nonconstant and $Jac(R,T)$ vanishes.  If we try to make this work while maintaining $RS + T$ and $T$ homogeneous, then we'll force $R$ to divide $T$, which you seem to want to avoid.  I'd suggest asking about the homogeneous case as a separate question.

Comment: @BadamBaplan, thank you for your comment, especially pointing out the helpful identity! If I am not wrong, $\operatorname{Jac}(R,T)=0$ just implies that $R=\lambda W^n$, $T=\mu W^m$, for some $\lambda, \mu \in k-\{0\}$ and homogeneous $W \in k[x,y]$, so $R$ not necessarily divides $T$. But I like your idea. ($R$ and $T$ are algebraically dependent).

Comment: @user237522 if $R = \lambda W^n, T = \mu W^m$ and $T$ has larger degree than $R$, then $m > n$ and it follows that $R$ divides $T$.

Comment: A remark about your identity: If $\operatorname{Jac}(R,S) \in k-\{0\}$ and $\operatorname{Jac}(R,T)=0$, then by CMW's theorem, $T \in k[R]$. Then $RS+T=R\tilde{S}+\nu$, for some $\nu \in k$ and $\tilde{S} \in k[x,y]$. (CMW'S theorem is Theorem 1 in: https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/740f/755a83a0f7354a1fb9a83d4b775993ae7ed1.pdf?_ga=2.132859214.1705010237.1560897052-325207994.1560897052). However, $\operatorname{Jac}(R,S)$ is not necessarily a non-zero scalar.

Comment: @BadamBaplan, thank you, nice! Indeed, $\deg(T) \geq \deg(R)$, since $RS+T$ is homogeneous, so $\deg(R)+\deg(S)=\deg(T)$.

Comment: Right, the aim of my first comment was just to point out that if you wanted to adapt this counterexample to $R,a$ homogeneous while avoiding $R$ divides $a$, then you would necessarily need to choose $S,T$ nonhomogeneous

Comment: @BadamBaplan, thanks for the clarification/explanation! I wish to assume that $S$ is homogeneous, so the specific counterexample would not work. I will post a new question about the homogeneous case.

Comment: @BadamBaplan, there is something that I do not understand: Also in the homogeneous case $a=RS$ works, taking $S$ homogeneous and obtaining $\operatorname{Jac}(R,a)=\operatorname{Jac}(R,RS)=R\operatorname{Jac}(R,S)$, with $\operatorname{Jac}(R,S)$ not necessarily a scalar.

Comment: @user237522 To clarify again, I was just commenting on how to "adapt this counterexample to $R,a$ homogeneous **while avoiding $R$ divides $a$**." Mohan's original comment settled your question as originally asked, even restricting to $R,a$ homogeneous.  But in your comments you seemed interested in restricting to the case where additionally $a$ is not a multiple of $R$.

Comment: @BadamBaplan, very nice, thank you very much! I now understand.